# No value given for one or more parameters

Tags: database, parameters, oledb

I dont know what;s wrong with my codes : PLEASE HELP ME :( when i run it it gives me an error above. :( no value... etc.. :(

```
Private Sub btnAdd_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnAdd.Click

Dim Str As String
Try
    Str = "insert into Students values("
    Str += txtNick.Text.Trim()
    Str += ","
    Str += """" & txtFirst.Text.Trim() & """"
    Str += ","
    Str += """" & txtLast.Text.Trim() & """"
    Str += ","
    Str += """" & txtAge.Text.Trim() & """"
    Str += ","
    Str += """" & txtGender.Text.Trim() & """"
    Str += ","
    Str += """" & txtAddress.Text.Trim() & """"
    Str += ","
    Str += txtContact.Text.Trim()
    Str += ")"
    Con.Open()
    Cmd = New OleDbCommand(Str, Con)
    Cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
    Dst.Clear()
    Dad = New OleDbDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM Students ORDER BY NickName", Con)
    Dad.Fill(Dst, "StudsInfo")
    MsgBox("Record inserted successfully...")
    Con.Close()
Catch ex As Exception
    MessageBox.Show("Could Not Insert Record!!!")
    MsgBox(ex.Message & " -  " & ex.Source)
    Con.Close()
End Try
```

End Sub

Comment: don't post all of your code, post only the relevant parts. No one is going to read the whole code this long.

Comment: i am having a problem in inserting new data :( please help me

Comment: sorry , I don't do prog. In this language.. (is it visual basic? :O )
maybe others could help.. :)

Answer (score 0):

Your insert aside from being wide open to SQL-injection is poor design. You should use parameters on it.  Also, if you table has 10 columns, but you only specific 6, that may be throwing it unless you explicitly tell which columns you are trying to insert...

By not knowing the database you are inserting into (VFP, dBASE, Excel, Access, etc), I don't know the parameter indicator for the sql, you will have to look into that.  I will just use "?" as a place-holder for each respective field for now.

Something like

```
Str = "insert into Students ( NickName, FirstName, LastName, " &
    "Age, Gender, Address, Contact ) " &
    "values " &
    "( ?parmNickName, ?parmFirstName, ?parmLastName, " & 
    "?parmAge, ?parmGender, ?parmAddress, ?parmContact )"

Con.Open()
Cmd = New OleDbCommand(Str, Con)

-- Now, add the parameters... Not using VB.Net, the command may be different
-- maybe something like .Parameters.AddWithValue() or similar...
Cmd.Parameters.Add( "parmNickName", txtNick.Text.Trim())
Cmd.Parameters.Add( "parmFirstName", txtFirst.Text.Trim())
Cmd.Parameters.Add( "parmLastName", txtLast.Text.Trim())
Cmd.Parameters.Add( "parmAge", txtAge.Text.Trim())
Cmd.Parameters.Add( "parmGender",txtGender.Text.Trim())
Cmd.Parameters.Add( "parmAddress", txtAddress.Text.Trim())
Cmd.Parameters.Add( "parmContact", txtContact.Text.Trim())


-- NOW, run the query to insert explicit fields and corresponding values
Cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
```